# How do I organize this data correctly using Mathematica in order to plot in polar coordinates?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

Below is my current code in Mathematica. I am trying to plot in polar coordinates from the `Points1` list but cannot figure out how to do this correctly.

For each `phi` value, there are `3` or more values for `r`. I'm assuming I need to organize these as pairs first, but am having trouble extracting the elements with the `||` in the middle. Any suggestions for how to organize these as coordinate pairs of `phi` and `r` would be greatly appreciated. The `||` appeared after finding the real.

Thanks for your time, and sorry if I goofed up this post as it is my first. -T

```
Points1 = {};

Do[Points1 = 
Append[Points1, {phivals[[i]], 
Reduce[{PolarDJ == 0 /. {\[CurlyPhi] -> phivals[[i]]}}, r, 
Reals]}], {i, Length[phivals]}]
```

---

```
Points1 =  {{0., r == -0.91018 || r == 0 || r == 0.91018}, {0.0628319, 
r == -0.905105 || r == -1.22951*10^-8 || r == 1.22951*10^-8 || 
r == 0.905105}, {0.125664, 
r == -0.890241 || r == 0 || r == 0.890241}, {0.188496, 
r == -0.866617 || r == 0 || r == 0.866617}, {0.251327, 
r == -0.835761 || r == 0 || r == 0.835761}, {0.314159, 
r == -0.799487 || r == 0.799487}, {0.376991, 
r == -0.759666 || r == -1.28907*10^-8 || r == 1.28907*10^-8 || 
r == 0.759666}, {0.439823, 
r == -0.718043 || r == 0 || r == 0.718043}, {0.502655, 
r == -0.676112 || r == -1.5092*10^-8 || r == 1.5092*10^-8 || 
r == 0.676112}, {0.565487, 
r == -0.635062 || r == -1.36407*10^-8 || r == 1.36407*10^-8 || 
r == 0.635062}, {0.628319, 
r == -0.595771 || r == 0 || r == 0.595771}, {0.69115, 
r == -0.558838 || r == -1.53443*10^-8 || r == 1.53443*10^-8 || 
r == 0.558838}, {0.753982, 
r == -0.524632 || r == 0 || r == 0.524632}, {0.816814, 
r == -0.493346 || r == 0 || r == 0.493346}, {0.879646, 
r == -0.465044 || r == 0 || r == 0.465044},..}
```

Comment: I replaced `theta` with `r` in your post, that was a mistake, right?

Comment: What is `phivals` and `PolarDJ`?

Comment: "PolarDJ" is an expression I wrote for a matrix determinant in polar coordinates and "phivals" is a table of values that span from 0 to 2pi with increments of pi/400. I'm writing code to model gravitational microlensing events. If you want to see more code, I can post it, but I didn't want to clutter the page. :)

Answer (score 1):

`||` is `Or` you can always investigate with `FullForm` and then use it to e.g. `ReplaceAll` with what you need. Here is one variation:

```
Thread /@ (Points1 /. r == v_ :> v /. Or -> List) // ListPolarPlot
```

[image]

`Thread` converts `{phi, {r1, r2, r3}}` to `{{phi, r1}, {phi, r2}, {phi, r3}}`

You could add `Catenate` but now each `phi` set has unique color.

Comment: Thank you so much! (The r and theta were correct initially).

Comment: @TiffanyVisgaitis I'm glad it works for you. Please take [a tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two somewhat shorter alternatives to Kuba's replacement method:

```
a = Tuples@{{#}, Last /@ #2} & @@@ Points1;

b = {#,r} /. {ToRules@#2} & @@@ Points1;

a === b   (* True *)

ListPolarPlot[a]
```

[image]